# Is there any community effort towards scala googleprotobuf "bindings"?

Tags: scala, code-generation, protocol-buffers

Subj. :)

Google Protocol Buffer looks like really convenient serialization facilities. However generated java classes are <s>suck</s> not so good:

- no Option[]s
- no closures
- too much copying
- etc.

i.e. it is not Scala :)

Are there any known effort towards Scala code generator for protobuf (it shouldn't be too complex) or probably any other protobuf-like library with a Scala interface?

Thanks!

P.S.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-scala looks dead and

https://github.com/jeffplaisance/scala-protobuf is just a wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

The latest effort I know of is [ScalaBuff](https://github.com/SandroGrzicic/ScalaBuff/network), started by Sandro Grzicic, and continued by Gerolf Seitz, who also started development of an corresponding [branch of his sbt-protobuf-plugin](https://github.com/gseitz/sbt-protobuf/tree/scalabuff).